# Calculating the lipschitz constant of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, lipschitz-functions

So I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^m y_i A_ix$$
where $A_i$ are $n$ by $n$ real symmetric positive definite matrices (not that it really matters in this case) for $i=1, \dots m$.

I would like to calculate the Lipschitz constant of $\nabla_x f(x,y)$ on the set that $\|x \| \leq 1$. When I fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^n\cap\{x: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ and take $y^1,y^2 \in \mathbb{R}^m$ I have

$$ \|\nabla_x f(x,y^1) - \nabla_x f(x,y^2)\| = \|\sum_{i=1}^m (y^1_i - y^2_i) A_ix\| $$
but I'm having trouble majorizing this for $L\|y^1 - y^2\|$. How can I calculate such an $L$ so that the inequality works?

Comment: @HeroZhang001 I am having doubts that a change of $\mapsto$ to $\to$ really improves a question that no one had an interest in since almost seven years.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no body had an interest in it since almost seven years.

Comment: @Kurt G. Sorry, I have obsessive-compulsive disorder. I am a perfectionist. When I see some imprecise language, I can't help modifying it

Comment: @HeroZhang001 . I admit that I was impressed by your skills to find those typos. :)

Comment: @KurtG. I do not think that is a good reason to close questions. Clearly, people like herozhang001 are still seeing it, so maybe it could still be answered.